# How can i combine both keyboard and on click combinations?

Tags: javascript, calculator

```js
let operator = "";
let currentValue = "";
let previousValue = "";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let clear = document.querySelector("#clear-btn");
  let equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
  let decimal = document.querySelector(".decimal");

  let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
  let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");

  let previousScreen = document.querySelector(".previous");
  let currentScreen = document.querySelector(".current");

  numbers.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
      currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    });
  });

  operators.forEach((op) => {
    op.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
      previousScreen.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator;
      currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    });
  });

  clear.addEventListener("click", () => {
    operator = "";
    currentValue = "";
    previousValue = "";
    previousScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
  });

  equal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentValue != "" && previousValue != "") {
      calculate();
      previousScreen.textContent = "";
      if (previousValue.length <= 5) {
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue;
      } else {
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue.slice(0, 5) + "...";
      }
    }
  });

  decimal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addDecimal();
  });
});

function handleNumber(num) {
  if (currentValue.length <= 5) {
    currentValue += num;
  }
}

function handleOperator(op) {
  operator = op;
  previousValue = currentValue;
  currentValue = "";
}

function calculate() {
  previousValue = Number(previousValue);
  currentValue = Number(currentValue);

  if (operator === "+") {
    previousValue += currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "-") {
    previousValue -= currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "x") {
    previousValue *= currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "/") {
    previousValue /= currentValue;
  }
  previousValue = roundNum(previousValue);
  previousValue = previousValue.toString();
  currentValue = previousValue.toString();
}

function roundNum(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
}

function addDecimal() {
  if (!currentValue.includes(".")) {
    currentValue += ".";
  }
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  let x = e.key;
  let choice;
  switch (x) {
    case "1":
      choice = document.querySelector(".one");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "2":
      choice = document.querySelector(".two");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "3":
      choice = document.querySelector(".three");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "4":
      choice = document.querySelector(".four");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "5":
      choice = document.querySelector(".five");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "6":
      choice = document.querySelector(".six");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "7":
      choice = document.querySelector(".seven");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "8":
      choice = document.querySelector(".eight");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "9":
      choice = document.querySelector(".nine");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "0":
      choice = document.querySelector(".zero");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "/":
      choice = document.querySelector(".division");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "*":
      choice = document.querySelector(".multiply");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "-":
      choice = document.querySelector(".minus");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "+":
      choice = document.querySelector(".plus");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case ".":
      choice = document.querySelector(".decimal");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "Enter":
      choice = document.querySelector(".equal");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "Backspace":
      choice = document.querySelector("#clear-btn");
      choice.click();
      break;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.number {
  border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.number:hover {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.operator {
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.operator:hover {
  background-color: paleturquoise;
}

.decimal {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.decimal:hover {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.equal {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.equal:hover {
  background-color: plum;
}

#clear-btn {
  border: 1px solid violet;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#clear-btn:hover {
  background-color: palevioletred;
}

.first-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#screen {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.previous {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.current {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="first-row">
      <div id="screen">
        <div class="previous"></div>
        <div class="current"></div>
      </div>
      <button id="clear-btn" class="btn">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number seven">7</button>
      <button class="btn number eight">8</button>
      <button class="btn number nine">9</button>
      <button class="btn operator division">/</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number four">4</button>
      <button class="btn number five">5</button>
      <button class="btn number six">6</button>
      <button class="btn operator multiply">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number one">1</button>
      <button class="btn number two">2</button>
      <button class="btn number three">3</button>
      <button class="btn operator minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn decimal">.</button>
      <button class="btn number zero">0</button>
      <button class="btn equal">=</button>
      <button class="btn operator plus">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if my code is best practice but when trying to implement both on click and keydown functions my application does not work. For example, type `5*5` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the answer shows). Then proceed to CLICK the `C` to clear and type `5*5` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. This time the answer will not be shown. I'm not sure what the error is. Is there a better way to implement both click and keydown functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general approach is fine. The problem is that the Enter key has a default action of clicking on the active button. Since the last button you clicked on was `C`, Enter is clicking on this again, which is clearing the result after it's displayed.

Call `e.preventDefault()` in the keydown listener to stop this.

```js
let operator = "";
let currentValue = "";
let previousValue = "";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let clear = document.querySelector("#clear-btn");
  let equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
  let decimal = document.querySelector(".decimal");

  let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
  let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");

  let previousScreen = document.querySelector(".previous");
  let currentScreen = document.querySelector(".current");

  numbers.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
      currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    });
  });

  operators.forEach((op) => {
    op.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
      previousScreen.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator;
      currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    });
  });

  clear.addEventListener("click", () => {
    operator = "";
    currentValue = "";
    previousValue = "";
    previousScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
  });

  equal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentValue != "" && previousValue != "") {
      calculate();
      previousScreen.textContent = "";
      if (previousValue.length <= 5) {
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue;
      } else {
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue.slice(0, 5) + "...";
      }
    }
  });

  decimal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addDecimal();
  });
});

function handleNumber(num) {
  if (currentValue.length <= 5) {
    currentValue += num;
  }
}

function handleOperator(op) {
  operator = op;
  previousValue = currentValue;
  currentValue = "";
}

function calculate() {
  previousValue = Number(previousValue);
  currentValue = Number(currentValue);

  if (operator === "+") {
    previousValue += currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "-") {
    previousValue -= currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "x") {
    previousValue *= currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "/") {
    previousValue /= currentValue;
  }
  previousValue = roundNum(previousValue);
  previousValue = previousValue.toString();
  currentValue = previousValue.toString();
}

function roundNum(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
}

function addDecimal() {
  if (!currentValue.includes(".")) {
    currentValue += ".";
  }
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let x = e.key;
  let choice;
  switch (x) {
    case "1":
      choice = document.querySelector(".one");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "2":
      choice = document.querySelector(".two");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "3":
      choice = document.querySelector(".three");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "4":
      choice = document.querySelector(".four");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "5":
      choice = document.querySelector(".five");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "6":
      choice = document.querySelector(".six");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "7":
      choice = document.querySelector(".seven");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "8":
      choice = document.querySelector(".eight");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "9":
      choice = document.querySelector(".nine");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "0":
      choice = document.querySelector(".zero");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "/":
      choice = document.querySelector(".division");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "*":
      choice = document.querySelector(".multiply");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "-":
      choice = document.querySelector(".minus");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "+":
      choice = document.querySelector(".plus");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case ".":
      choice = document.querySelector(".decimal");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "Enter":
      choice = document.querySelector(".equal");
      choice.click();
      break;
    case "Backspace":
      choice = document.querySelector("#clear-btn");
      choice.click();
      break;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.number {
  border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.number:hover {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.operator {
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.operator:hover {
  background-color: paleturquoise;
}

.decimal {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.decimal:hover {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.equal {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.equal:hover {
  background-color: plum;
}

#clear-btn {
  border: 1px solid violet;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#clear-btn:hover {
  background-color: palevioletred;
}

.first-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#screen {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.previous {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.current {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="first-row">
      <div id="screen">
        <div class="previous"></div>
        <div class="current"></div>
      </div>
      <button id="clear-btn" class="btn">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number seven">7</button>
      <button class="btn number eight">8</button>
      <button class="btn number nine">9</button>
      <button class="btn operator division">/</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number four">4</button>
      <button class="btn number five">5</button>
      <button class="btn number six">6</button>
      <button class="btn operator multiply">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn number one">1</button>
      <button class="btn number two">2</button>
      <button class="btn number three">3</button>
      <button class="btn operator minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="other-rows">
      <button class="btn decimal">.</button>
      <button class="btn number zero">0</button>
      <button class="btn equal">=</button>
      <button class="btn operator plus">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```